# Why does sdkman not update Java SDK version for project subdirectories?

Tags: java, sdk, sdkman

After setting the Java version for a project directory via the .sdkmanenv file, the Java versions only gets updated when navigating to the root directory.

Is this just expected behavior?
Does the .sdkmanrc file need to be propagated to all sub-directories?

Example:

```
~ % mkdir root_dir
~ % cd root_dir
root_dir % mkdir sub_dir
root_dir % sdk env init
  .sdkmanrc created.
root_dir % cat .sdkmanrc
  # Enable auto-env through the sdkman_auto_env 
  config
  # Add key=value pairs of SDKs to use below
  java=8.0.345-tem
root_dir % sed -i"" -e 's/8.0.345-tem/11.0.16-tem/' .sdkmanrc
root_dir % cat .sdkmanrc
  # Enable auto-env through the sdkman_auto_env config
  # Add key=value pairs of SDKs to use below
  java=11.0.16-tem
root_dir % cd ..
~ % cd root_dir/sub_dir
sub_dir % cd ..
  Using java version 11.0.16-tem in this shell.
root_dir % cd ..
  Restored java version to 8.0.345-tem (default)
```

For reference, I am using the following versions of sdkman and macOS, respectively.

```
% sdk version
SDKMAN 5.16.0

#macOS version
% sw_vers -productVersion
12.5.1
```

Also, I have 'sdkman_auto_env=true' set via 'sdk config'

```
% grep sdkman_auto_env .sdkman/etc/config
sdkman_auto_env=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, as for now it's not supported. There is an open feature request ([#1102](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/1102)) to support this.

It [was also suggested to respect the closest `.sdkmanrc`](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/756#issuecomment-622947190) on the initial auto-env feature implementation, but was decided to keep it simple first.